# Curly brackets in array values, Javascript

Tags: javascript, summernote

I'm having problems getting this autocomplete function to work when my array values begin and end with curly brackets.

Say I have an array with values like this:

```
var hints = ["{{ticket_id}}","{{requestor_id}}","{{date_created}}"]
```

Here's my JS:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#editor_subject").summernote({
            toolbar: [],
            hint: {
               words: hints,
               match: /\b(\w{1,})$/,
               search: function (keyword, callback) {
                 callback($.grep(this.words, function (item) {
                   return item.indexOf(keyword) === 0;
                 }));
               }
             }                
        });
    });
</script>
```

So the they way it should work, is if I type something like {{ti it should autocomplete and fill in the rest of the word with {{ticket_id}}, but it's not working. If I remove the curly brackets from the values in the array, it works just fine.

How can I accomplish this? I'm assuming its the regexp used in the match section.

Thanks,

Comment: Try the regex `\{\{\b(\w{1,})$`

Comment: try removing $ from the end of regex because \w don't match curly brackets. `"{{ticket_id}}".match(/\b(\w{1,})/)`

Comment: I tried \{\{\b(\w{1,})$ and I'm getting an invalid token error.  Guessing it's the way summernote handles the data.

Comment: I also tried removing the $ from the end, no error but that didn't fix the issue either.

Answer (score 0):

This regex ended up working for me:

/(.{1,})$/

The 2 mentioned above did not.